# Prevent Column going below zero and echo warning

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with column character_gold. With character_gold you can train strength (another column). But trains continue even if character_gold is 0 and as a result character_gold values become negative:

```
if (isset($_POST['train_strength'])) {
    $trainstrength = "UPDATE user_character
        SET strength_trains = strength_trains + 1,
        trained_strength = trained_strength +1,
        character_gold = character_gold - $gold_to_next_strength
        WHERE ID = $currentUser";
    mysqli_query($con, $trainstrength);
    mysqli_close($con);

    header('Location: account.php');
}
```

How can I prevent that and also echoing an alert?

Comment: Check the amount of gold a character has before updating.

Comment: No need to check: character_gold = greatest(character_gold - $gold_to_next_strength,0)

Comment: @Strawberry Then how would you echo the alert?